# Mulesoft/Anypoint File Connectors + Python script

Tags: python, mule, mule-studio

I decided to try the Mulesoft ESB and Anypoint. It works great until I add some script. 
In my test File are redirect to folder based on theirs extension.
Then in a directory some files received a modification by a python script.
And that's where it doesn't work anymore.
If I modify the file it's seems to close the flow.
So how can I avoid that?

Thanks.

Here is the error message:

```
ERROR 2015-07-20 09:20:32,114 [[filetransfer].FileR.dispatcher.15] org.mule.exception.DefaultMessagingExceptionStrategy: 
********************************************************************************
Message               : Failed to route event via endpoint: DefaultOutboundEndpoint{endpointUri=file:///home/glass/AnypointStudio/workspace/filetransfer/Data/temp, connector=FileConnector
{
  name=FileR
  lifecycle=start
  this=70a37e7f
  numberOfConcurrentTransactedReceivers=4
  createMultipleTransactedReceivers=true
  connected=true
  supportedProtocols=[file]
  serviceOverrides=<none>
}
,  name='endpoint.file.home.glass.AnypointStudio.workspace.filetransfer.Data.temp', mep=ONE_WAY, properties={}, transactionConfig=Transaction{factory=null, action=INDIFFERENT, timeout=0}, deleteUnacceptedMessages=false, initialState=started, responseTimeout=10000, endpointEncoding=UTF-8, disableTransportTransformer=false}. Message payload is of type: ReceiverFileInputStream
Type                  : org.mule.api.transport.DispatchException
Code                  : MULE_ERROR--2
Payload               : org.mule.transport.file.ReceiverFileInputStream@18806dc1
JavaDoc               : http://www.mulesoft.org/docs/site/current3/apidocs/org/mule/api/transport/DispatchException.html
********************************************************************************
Exception stack is:
1. Stream Closed (java.io.IOException)
  java.io.FileInputStream:-2 (null)
2. Failed to route event via endpoint: DefaultOutboundEndpoint{endpointUri=file:///home/glass/AnypointStudio/workspace/filetransfer/Data/temp, connector=FileConnector
{
  name=FileR
  lifecycle=start
  this=70a37e7f
  numberOfConcurrentTransactedReceivers=4
  createMultipleTransactedReceivers=true
  connected=true
  supportedProtocols=[file]
  serviceOverrides=<none>
}
,  name='endpoint.file.home.glass.AnypointStudio.workspace.filetransfer.Data.temp', mep=ONE_WAY, properties={}, transactionConfig=Transaction{factory=null, action=INDIFFERENT, timeout=0}, deleteUnacceptedMessages=false, initialState=started, responseTimeout=10000, endpointEncoding=UTF-8, disableTransportTransformer=false}. Message payload is of type: ReceiverFileInputStream (org.mule.api.transport.DispatchException)
  org.mule.transport.AbstractMessageDispatcher:117 (http://www.mulesoft.org/docs/site/current3/apidocs/org/mule/api/transport/DispatchException.html)
********************************************************************************
Root Exception stack trace:
java.io.IOException: Stream Closed
    at java.io.FileInputStream.readBytes(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.read(FileInputStream.java:243)
    at org.mule.util.IOUtils.copyLarge(IOUtils.java:239)
    at org.mule.transport.file.FileMessageDispatcher.doDispatch(FileMessageDispatcher.java:80)
    at org.mule.transport.AbstractMessageDispatcher.process(AbstractMessageDispatcher.java:107)
    at org.mule.transport.AbstractConnector$DispatcherMessageProcessor.process(AbstractConnector.java:2662)
    at org.mule.execution.ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.execute(ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.java:24)
    at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.execute(MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.java:107)
    at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.execute(MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.java:44)
    at org.mule.processor.BlockingProcessorExecutor.executeNext(BlockingProcessorExecutor.java:94)
    at org.mule.processor.BlockingProcessorExecutor.execute(BlockingProcessorExecutor.java:56)
    at org.mule.interceptor.AbstractEnvelopeInterceptor.processBlocking(AbstractEnvelopeInterceptor.java:58)
    at org.mule.processor.AbstractRequestResponseMessageProcessor.process(AbstractRequestResponseMessageProcessor.java:47)
    at org.mule.processor.AsyncInterceptingMessageProcessor.processNextTimed(AsyncInterceptingMessageProcessor.java:123)
    at org.mule.processor.AsyncInterceptingMessageProcessor$AsyncMessageProcessorWorker$1.process(AsyncInterceptingMessageProcessor.java:208)
    at org.mule.processor.AsyncInterceptingMessageProcessor$AsyncMessageProcessorWorker$1.process(AsyncInterceptingMessageProcessor.java:201)
    at org.mule.execution.ExecuteCallbackInterceptor.execute(ExecuteCallbackInterceptor.java:16)
    at org.mule.execution.CommitTransactionInterceptor.execute(CommitTransactionInterceptor.java:35)
    at org.mule.execution.CommitTransactionInterceptor.execute(CommitTransactionInterceptor.java:22)
    at org.mule.execution.HandleExceptionInterceptor.execute(HandleExceptionInterceptor.java:30)
    at org.mule.execution.HandleExceptionInterceptor.execute(HandleExceptionInterceptor.java:14)
    at org.mule.execution.BeginAndResolveTransactionInterceptor.execute(BeginAndResolveTransactionInterceptor.java:67)
    at org.mule.execution.ResolvePreviousTransactionInterceptor.execute(ResolvePreviousTransactionInterceptor.java:44)
    at org.mule.execution.SuspendXaTransactionInterceptor.execute(SuspendXaTransactionInterceptor.java:50)
    at org.mule.execution.ValidateTransactionalStateInterceptor.execute(ValidateTransactionalStateInterceptor.java:40)
    at org.mule.execution.IsolateCurrentTransactionInterceptor.execute(IsolateCurrentTransactionInterceptor.java:41)
    at org.mule.execution.ExternalTransactionInterceptor.execute(ExternalTransactionInterceptor.java:48)
    at org.mule.execution.RethrowExceptionInterceptor.execute(RethrowExceptionInterceptor.java:28)
    at org.mule.execution.RethrowExceptionInterceptor.execute(RethrowExceptionInterceptor.java:13)
    at org.mule.execution.TransactionalErrorHandlingExecutionTemplate.execute(TransactionalErrorHandlingExecutionTemplate.java:110)
    at org.mule.execution.TransactionalErrorHandlingExecutionTemplate.execute(TransactionalErrorHandlingExecutionTemplate.java:30)
    at org.mule.processor.AsyncInterceptingMessageProcessor$AsyncMessageProcessorWorker.doRun(AsyncInterceptingMessageProcessor.java:200)
    at org.mule.work.AbstractMuleEventWork.run(AbstractMuleEventWork.java:49)
    at org.mule.work.WorkerContext.run(WorkerContext.java:286)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

********************************************************************************
```

And here is the XML with the python script

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<mule xmlns:scripting="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/scripting" xmlns:metadata="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/metadata" xmlns:tracking="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ee/tracking" xmlns:file="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/file" xmlns="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core" xmlns:doc="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/documentation"
    xmlns:spring="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" version="EE-3.7.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-current.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core/current/mule.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/file http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/file/current/mule-file.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ee/tracking http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ee/tracking/current/mule-tracking-ee.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/scripting http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/scripting/current/mule-scripting.xsd">
    <file:connector name="FileR" readFromDirectory="/home/glass/AnypointStudio/workspace/filetransfer/Data/MInbox" autoDelete="true" streaming="true" recursive="true" validateConnections="true" doc:name="File"/>
    <flow name="Dispatcher">
        <file:inbound-endpoint path="/home/glass/AnypointStudio/workspace/filetransfer/Data/Inbox" responseTimeout="10000" doc:name="Input" connector-ref="FileR"/>
        <logger message="name : #[originalFilename]" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
        <choice doc:name="Choice">
            <when expression="#[regex('^.*(iso|ISO)' , originalFilename)]">
                <file:outbound-endpoint path="/home/glass/AnypointStudio/workspace/filetransfer/Data/BIGFILE" responseTimeout="10000" doc:name="FileISO"/>
            </when>
            <when expression="#[regex('^.*xml' , originalFilename)]">
                <file:outbound-endpoint path="/home/glass/AnypointStudio/workspace/filetransfer/Data/temp" responseTimeout="10000" doc:name="File"/>
                <scripting:transformer doc:name="Python">
                    <scripting:script engine="jython"><![CDATA[import os

print("__________________________________________________________________")

new_name = "test-" + originalFilename
os.rename(originalFilename, new_name)
print(new_name)]]></scripting:script>
                </scripting:transformer>
            </when>
            <otherwise>
                <file:outbound-endpoint path="/home/glass/AnypointStudio/workspace/filetransfer/Data/DEFAULT" responseTimeout="10000" doc:name="FileDefault"/>
            </otherwise>
        </choice>
    </flow>
</mule>
```

Answer (score 0):

`file:outbound-endpoint` is `one-way` which means that, by default, Mule will run the dispatch action in a different thread. Thus the:

```
os.rename(originalFilename, new_name)
```

happens while `file:outbound-endpoint` is still copying data from the stream opened on `originalFilename`.

Make the flow synchronous with:

```
<flow name="Dispatcher" processingStrategy="synchronous">
```

to force Mule to do everything with the same thread.